# Getting a 2D "pixel" cloud to follow a mouse

Tags: 2d, physics, unity

I'm working on a 2D game trying to get a "cloud" of a few hundred tiny cubes or discs to follow my mouse cursor without overlapping each other.

However, using the physics engine introduces performance sluggishness as the number of discs grows and the collision detection is generally wonky.

Is there an easy way to optimise the engine for this kind of thing? If not, would I be better off just switching the engine off and writing something of my own? (Clutching at straws here, but:) Are there any good resources or examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, using a physics engine for that would be a little overkill. I suggest you implement a flocking algorithm. The basics of which are:

- Separation: Steer to avoid crowding local flockmates
- Alignment: Steer towards the average heading of local flockmates
- Cohesion: Steer to move toward the average position of local flockmates

You can see it in action [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) and get some [details on its implementation](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/). You'll do some minor tweaking to include applying a force towards the mouse pointer.

Comment: You cab use a virtual dynamic grid or other spatial partitioning to make flocking efficient if you have a lot of boids you can't process naively, too.  Plenty of ways to optimize.